# Uninstalling JDK 8 on OSX

Tags: java, macos

How can I cleanse my Mac of Java 8 -- jdk, not jre or plugin, which I don't care about?  I need to downgrade to jdk 7.  I've found docs online but they're all about the java plugin.  If I try simply installing jdk 7 (on top of 8), the 8 is still there.

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall a JDK simply by deleting the appropriate directory under `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` where it is installed.  But note that browsers, Java Web Start and double-clickable app bundles created with Oracle's appbundler will always use the "public JRE" under `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins`, and that will remain as Java 8 unless you uninstall it separately.

But you may not actually need to uninstall Java 8 - the command line tools such as `java` and `javac` respect `JAVA_HOME`, so you can have both versions installed side by side and pick the appropriate one with `/usr/libexec/java_home`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v '1.7*'`
```

Answer (score 0):

On my machine, I get the following output from terminal:

```
> /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

> /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_07.jdk/Contents/Home

> /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Check yours and let me know.